VBA for Word code that removes paragraph rules and replaces them with cell borders
I'm trying to write some code that will replace certain paragraph styles that have a bottom border (in tables) with other paragraph styles that have no bottom border but a cell border instead (if that makes sense). The paragraph styles have been rigorously applied in the Word document, so that isn't the problem. I'm very new to VBA coding and keen to learn more.
The code below is what I've managed to extract from various online sources, and tried to adapt it to what I need, but nothing is happening when I run the macro. Any help would be much appreciated.
Sub AutoFormatTables2024()
'Removes paragraph rules and replaces them with cell borders - does nothing!'
Dim oCell As Cell
Dim oTable As Table
For Each oTable In ActiveDocument.Tables
For Each oCell In oTable.Range.Cells
With oCell
If Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("_table figshead thin") = True Then
Options.DefaultBorderLineWidth = wdLineWidth050pt
Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("_table figshead")
With Selection.Borders(wdBorderBottom)
.LineStyle = Options.DefaultBorderLineStyle
.LineWidth = Options.DefaultBorderLineWidth
.Color = Options.DefaultBorderColor
End With
ElseIf Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("_table figs thin") = True Then
Options.DefaultBorderLineWidth = wdLineWidth050pt
Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("_table figs")
With Selection.Borders(wdBorderBottom)
.LineStyle = Options.DefaultBorderLineStyle
.LineWidth = Options.DefaultBorderLineWidth
.Color = Options.DefaultBorderColor
End With
ElseIf Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("_table figs thick") = True Then
Options.DefaultBorderLineWidth = wdLineWidth150pt
Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("_table figs")
With Selection.Borders(wdBorderBottom)
.LineStyle = Options.DefaultBorderLineStyle
.LineWidth = Options.DefaultBorderLineWidth
.Color = Options.DefaultBorderColor
End With
End If
End With
Next oCell
DoEvents
Next oTable
MsgBox "All done!"
End Sub


Your code processes the table by cell but does nothing at all to the cell. Instead your code works with Selection, never a good idea, but doesn't actually select anything related to the table. If you intend to add a cell border then use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.cell.borders . To check the style in the cell use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.cell.range

Thanks for your quick response! Pardon my ignorance, but can I use something else apart from Selection?

Yes, you can use Cell and I provided you with two links to documentation that will help you with that. You should also make use of the Object Browser and online help in the VB Editor to learn more about the available properties and methods.

Thanks for your suggestions! I've come up with some code using Case which works, but has two problems: if there is a character style applied, the macro ignores that text; and the text it does work on becomes left aligned, when I need it to ignore alignment and leave it as it was. I haven't managed to find anything yet how to ignore attributes. Can anyone help, please?
